# Linux Command : Why does the redirection operator - | i.e. piping fail here?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, sh

I was working my way through a primer on Shell (Bash) Scripting and had the following doubt :

> - Why does not the following command print the contents of `cp's` directory : `which cp | ls -l`
> - Does not piping by definition mean that we pass the output of one command to another i.e. redirect the output ?

Can someone help me out ? I am a newbie ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `which` is being piped to the standard input of `ls`. However, `ls` doesn't take anything on standard input. You want it (I presume) to be passed as a parameter. There are a couple of ways of doing that:

```
which cp | xargs ls -l
```

or

```
ls -l `which cp`
```

or

```
ls -l $(which cp)
```

In the first example the `xargs` command takes the standard output of the previous previous command and makes each line a parameter to the command whose name immediately follows `xargs`. So, for instance

```
find / | xargs ls -l
```

will do an `ls -l` on each file in the filesystem (there are some issues with this with peculiarly named files but that's beyond the scope of this answer).

The remaining two are broadly equivalent and use the shell to do this, expanding the output from `which` into the command line for `cp`.

Comment: Hi , @abligh , thank you very much ; how do I come to know that ls does not take anything from STDIN ?

Comment: One answer: read the man page. Better answer: when you type `ls -l /path/to/file` and press enter, does the command wait for you to provide more data after that through the keyboard? No it doesn't. Something like `tr a z` would.

Comment: And to answer your second bullet point; yes, that's what it does.  You can, for example, do `which cp | nl` to get [`nl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nl.1.html) to number the lines it receives.  This is another example of a command which does read and process its standard input; other popular examples are `head`, `tail`, `sed`, `tac`, `read`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee :) ; can I ask you , what would be a good way to build up a comprehensive knowledge of bash starting from ground-up ; hope am not being intrusive :)

Comment: The [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has a list of links; studying those should be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

It would be,

```
$ ls -l $(which cp)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 130304 Mar 24  2014 /bin/cp
```

OR

```
$ which cp | xargs ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 130304 Mar 24  2014 /bin/cp
```

To pass the output of one command as parameter of another command, you need to use `xargs` along with the pipe symbol.

From `man xargs`

> xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input.xargs reads items
>          from  the  standard  input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected
>          with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines, and  executes
>          the  command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any initial-
>          arguments followed by items read from standard input.  Blank  lines  on
>          the standard input are ignored.